# Partial View MVC 5 : "A space or line break was encountered after the "@" character

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Here is the error:

> "A space or line break was encountered after the "@" character.  Only valid identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid at the start of a code block and they must occur immediately following "@" with no space in between.

I am using MVC 5 and working through the book Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 - Adam Freeman. Here is the List.cshtml.

Main view

```
@model SS.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

@foreach (var p in Model.Products) 
{
    @Html.Partial("ProductSummary", p)
}

<div class="pager">
    @Html.PageLinks((SS.WebUI.Models.PagingInfo)Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x }))
</div>
```

Partial view

```
@model SS.Domain.Entities.Product
<div class="well">
  <h3><strong>@Model.Name</strong>
    <span class="pull-right label labelprimary"> @ Model.Price.ToString("c") </span>
  </h3>
  <span class="lead"> @Model.Description</span>
</div>
```

I have tried various syntaxes and cannot get it to work - any help will be apprecaited!

Comment: The code in your view looks OK. You need to post the partial view (that's probably where the error is).

Comment: I have tried this and get exactly the same error:

Comment: @foreach (var p in Model.Products) 
{
    Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary", p);
}

Comment: That's not the partial view!

Comment: ProductSummary is the partial view - I quote the steps:

Comment: To add the partial view, right-click the /Views/Shared folder in the SportsStore.WebUI project and select
Add View from the pop-up menu. Set View Name to ProductSummary, set Template to Empty, select
Product from the Model Class drop-down list and check the Create As A Partial View box, as shown

Comment: What are you talking about? The error you are getting is because your razor code is not correct - the message should be obvious!. The code in the main view looks OK (assuming that's the real code and you have not made a typo), which means that the code in your partial view is not. I have asked you to post the code in the partial. If you don't, then I can't help.

Comment: Ok here is the contents of the partial view

Comment: @model SS.Domain.Entities.Product
<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label labelprimary">
            @
            Model.Price.ToString("c")
        </span>
    </h3>
    <span class="lead"> @Model.Description</span>
</div>

Comment: Ok - I see what you mean - there was a typo in the partial view code , the @ sign was on its own line.. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the space in `@ Model.Price.ToString`. In future edit your question, don't add relevant code in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you check your partial view code:
 @ Model.Price.ToString("c")

There is space after @ for Model.Price.. **@ Model.Price.ToString("c") --> @Model.Price.ToString("c")**